# Getting a CSS table with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried to get the data from this table but I have been unable to do so: https://datagolf.ca/player-trends

I have tried many things for the last few hours, below is my most recent when just returns an empty list.

```py
import bs4
import requests

res = requests.get('https://datagolf.ca/player-trends')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "table")

table
```

Is the issue something similar to this:

[Scrape of table with only 'div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413362/scrape-of-table-with-only-divs)

Comment: You probably need to use selenium to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This page is java script rendered. Take a closer look at what `requests.get('https://datagolf.ca/player-trends')` actually returns. It does not contain the table.

Despite that it pulls the data from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hprrfklqs5q0oge/player_trends_dev.csv?dl=1

Comment: Magic thanks I have just taken that straight into a dataframe